# Declare variable referencing a table column type in Oracle nested procedure inside plqsl block

Tags: oracle, plsql, dbeaver, oracle19c

I am getting an error declaring a variable referencing a table column type in an Oracle nested procedure. I'm using dbeaver Community 23.0.3.202304240616.

Here is the code:

```
DECLARE 
    GLOBAL_VAR AREA.AREA_CD_AREA_UID%TYPE := 0;
    PROCEDURE SUB_TEST(SUB_PAR NUMBER)
    IS 
        SUB_VAR_1 NUMBER := 0;
        SUB_VAR_2 AREA.AREA_CD_AREA_UID%TYPE := 0;
    BEGIN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SUB_TEST');
    END SUB_TEST;

BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(GLOBAL_VAR);    
    SUB_TEST(1);
END;
```

The error is

```
Error occurred during SQL script execution

Reason:
SQL Error [6550] [65000]: ORA-06550: line 9, column 14:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function pragma procedure
```

It works if I remove SUB_VAR_2 declaration and GLOBAL_VAR shows the type is valid.

This [article](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00815) has some subprogram examples but none uses a custom type at a nested procedure. There's one with a rowtype which also worked for me changing `SUB_VAR_2` type to `AREA%ROWTYPE`.

**EDIT 1**

As requested, the code that works using ROWTYPE:

```
DECLARE 
    GLOBAL_VAR AREA.AREA_CD_AREA_UID%TYPE := 0;
    PROCEDURE SUB_TEST(SUB_PAR NUMBER)
    IS 
        SUB_VAR_1 NUMBER := 0;
--      SUB_VAR_2 AREA.AREA_CD_AREA_UID%TYPE := 0;
        SUB_REC AREA%ROWTYPE;
    BEGIN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SUB_TEST');
    END SUB_TEST;

BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(GLOBAL_VAR);    
    SUB_TEST(1);
END;
```

Comment: Your code works [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/avCS6mPs)

Comment: As an aside, `AREA.AREA_CD_AREA_UID%TYPE` is not a custom type. It is a reference that the variable has same data type as the referenced column.

Comment: @AlexPoole code added, the blank like is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

When I run this on Oracle 21c XE

```
set serveroutput on size unlimited

create table area (
  AREA_CD_AREA_UID  number(9)
)
/


DECLARE 
    GLOBAL_VAR AREA.AREA_CD_AREA_UID%TYPE := 0;
    PROCEDURE SUB_TEST(SUB_PAR NUMBER)
    IS 
        SUB_VAR_1 NUMBER := 0;
        SUB_VAR_2 AREA.AREA_CD_AREA_UID%TYPE := 0;
    BEGIN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SUB_TEST');
    END SUB_TEST;

BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(GLOBAL_VAR);    
    SUB_TEST(1);
END;
/
```

I get this

```
SQL> 

Table created

0
SUB_TEST

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed


SQL>
```

Which is as I expect.

So all I can think it may be a problem with your database specifically or there is a problem related to some code excluded from your question.

Comment: Could it be a dbeaver bug?

Comment: @Isborg difficult for me to confirm reliably either way as I don't use dbeaver. A way to prove is to run the script natively in SQLplus and see if problem persists. If not then likely dbeaver.

Comment: [Bug](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/19827) reported.